# Updating Helm subcharts fails without a clear error

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

While trying to add/update a dependency to a helm chart I'm getting this error. No helm plugins are installed with the name `helm-manager`.

```sh
$ helm dep update                                                                                                                                
Getting updates for unmanaged Helm repositories...
...Unable to get an update from the "https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/" chart repository:
        failed to fetch https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/index.yaml : 403 Forbidden
...Unable to get an update from the "https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/" chart repository:
        failed to fetch https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/index.yaml : 403 Forbidden
Hang tight while we grab the latest from your chart repositories...
...Successfully got an update from the "bitnami" chart repository
Update Complete. Happy Helming!
Error: no cached repository for helm-manager-1067d9c6027b8c3f27b49e40521d64be96ea412858d8e45064fa44afd3966ddc found. (try 'helm repo update'): open /Users/<redacted>/Library/Caches/helm/repository/helm-manager-1067d9c6027b8c3f27b49e40521d64be96ea412858d8e45064fa44
afd3966ddc-index.yaml: no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stable and incubator repositories of the Helm charts have been moved to a new location.
You must updated URI in charts.yaml (or requirements.yaml) to point to the new repositories in order to let the Helm dependency resolver find the correct location.

| Name | Old Location | New Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| stable | https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com | https://charts.helm.sh/stable |
| incubator | https://kubernetes-charts-incubator.storage.googleapis.com | https://charts.helm.sh/incubator |

After that you should be able to run `helm dep update` without further modifications.

Answer (score 2):

I get this sometimes when there's a mismatch between my `Chart.yaml` and the configuration of my subchart dependencies.

For instance:

`Chart.yaml`:

```yaml
dependencies:
- name: foo
  ...
- name: bar
  ...
```

`values.yaml`:

```yaml
foo: 
  flag: true
# but no entry for bar
```

It may be an artifact of some other element of my configuration (Artifactory hosting a proxy of the world for Helm) but I find myself running into this frequently enough that I hope this answer may help someone else.